# Pathfinder ACG: When do I use the Character Add-On cards?

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

I recently bought the Pathfinder Adventure Card Game, and liked it so much that I then also got all the Add-Ons in quick succession. But I am a bit unsure when to add the cards from the Character Add-On to the Base Set.

Do I

- only include them when playing with more than 4 characters
- only include them when playing one of the additional characters from the set
- or can I just leave them in the box, shuffled in among the Base Set?

Answer (score 4):

The Character Add-On pack adds 4 more character classes and additional monsters, weapons, and equipment. It allows you to play with up to 6 people (as opposed to the 4-player limit without it). You *don't* need to reserve those character classes for games with more than 4; use them in any session you want.

The rest of the cards are indeed meant to be added to the main set, so go ahead and shuffle them in.